# Delphi XE8 - Send Notification from Parse using VCL app

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am learning the new Baas technology with XE8.

I created a small app to receive notification on Android mobiles using Parse.
Everything is working fine when the notification message is sent from Parse web site.

However when my VCL app send the notification with BackendPush component, nothing is coming in mobile phone.

The messages are sending correctly because I can see them on Parse site. Their status is different than the one sent from Parse .

Here are my VCL messages Status on Parse:

```
Type: API, target: Chanels.
```

When sent on Parse site:

```
Type : Campaign, Target: Everyone.
```

What should I do to get my VCL messages arrive on mobile phone.

My code:

```
BackendPush1.Message:=Memo1.Lines.Text;
BackendPush1.Push;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should try to be more specific on your target device as follows:

```
BackendPush1.Target.Add('{ "where": { "installationId": "'+guid.Text+'" }}');
```

or

```
BackendPush1.Target.Add('{ "where": { "deviceType": "android" }}');
```

Regards!